# Magento : get shopping cart list

Tags: api, magento, soap, shopping-cart

is it possible to get shopping cart list from magento via soap API ? i want to get shopping cart of customer but i cant find any api for this in this link : [Magento API SOAP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's available through the checkout->cart section. Check the documentation at:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html

Comment: in this API we should send cart id as parameter but i don't known customer cart id !

Comment: Where do you need to access this information?  Using the API you have to know what customer ID you are dealing with in order to get that information.  IF it where just in the frontend you could instead use the current customer, as in - the one viewing the page.

Comment: in my application i want to add items to customer shopping cart or get information of customer shopping cart

Comment: yes but what customer?  just a random one?  there is no way you can get a specific customer cart without also knowing what customer - it's like asking for a phone number without having the persons name.

Comment: how do i get all quotes

Comment: This is api resource required id of quote but @mahdi ask about list of all available carts for user.